# java execution by inheriting from file from shared folder

Tags: java

I have two files, one in my local machine and another in a shared folder(from another machine).

My class on the localmachine has to inherit  from the class in the file in the shared folder.

How can I perform this inheritance?

I tried by giving set `CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;//(machineNo)/(foldername);` but this did not work.

Comment: I suppose just copying them both into the same directory is out of the question?

Comment: it should not be copied into the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `URLClassLoader` can be used to easily develop an application capable of loading classes and resources from remote servers. First, you need to define the URLs to be searched for classes. Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory, otherwise the URL is assumed to refer to a JAR file which will be opened as needed. Once an instance of the URLClassLoader is constructed, the `loadClass(String name)` method of the ClassLoader class is used to load the class with the specified name. Once a class has been loaded, an instance can be created (this means that the constructor will be invoked).

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyLoader {
   public static void main (String argv[]) throws Exception {

      URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("http://www.javacourses.com/classes/") });

      // Load class from class loader. argv[0] is the name of the class to be loaded
      Class c = loader.loadClass (argv[0]);

      // Create an instance of the class just loaded
      Object o = c.newInstance();

  }
}
```

You can read full article [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/classloaders/)

Answer (score 0):

If by inherit you mean extend, then simply loading the class won't suffice.

You will need some bytecode-manipulation library like [cglib](/questions/tagged/cglib), to create derived classes on the fly. (Not saying it's a herculean task, but it has a lot of possible pitfalls, so beware :) )

Comment: @Rob Kielty: thank you for your edit, I'm kind of a newbie here.